# Building basic plot R Shiny data from CSV

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

[image]Ok Im an R newbie but this shouldnt be this hard  Im trying to run a very basic scattered plot in Shiny like I did in R Studio based on some CSV data.  When I run the Shiny app I get a blank space for the graph.  The graph works totally fine when i run it in R studio.  If anyone has any ideal please let me know[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plyr)
# Simple header -----------------------------------------------------------
header <- dashboardHeader(title="Basic")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("Scores", height = 250)),
    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin="black")

# Setup Shiny app back-end components -------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) { 

  output$scatteredplot <- renderPlot ({
    data <- read.csv("Scores.csv")
    averageTime<-ddply(data, .(IP, OS), summarize, time=mean(time), score=mean(score), status=mean(status))
    plot(averageTime$RemediationTime,averageTime$score,xlab="time", ylab="score")
  })


  }

# Render Shiny app --------------------------------------------------------

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in the combination of the following two rows

```
box(plotOutput("Scores", height = 250)),
```

here you look for a plot called Scores, but

```
output$scatteredplot <- renderPlot ({
```

you only define a plot called scatteredplot

so replace the last line with

```
output$Scores <- renderPlot ({
```

actually there is also a superfluous comma in

```
 box(plotOutput("Scores", height = 250)),
```

but this was probably to generate a minimum reproducible example

Comment: Why? You shouldn't ;)

Comment: I had a example template I was using infront of me and didnt even notice the assignment operator.  Aye thank you very much for this